# How to close intellij auto sort imports?

Tags: intellij-idea

IDEA version : 2019.3.1 x64

I know Settings | Code Style | Java | Imports,
but not found where close;

I don't like idea auto change original import order.
how to close IDEA self-assertion function.Thanks!

[image: problem]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `Settings > General > Auto Import` uncheck `Optimize imports on the fly`. Also while reformatting, you may disable it by unchecking `Optimize Imports` in Reformat Code Dialog.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Disabling the `Optimize imports on the fly` should help in this case but it also disables the feature for removing unnecessary imports. 
Please vote on the related request if you feel that it breaks your workflow [IDEABKL-6456](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6456).

Comment: Thank you @EgorKlepikov for both information and sharing the link.